# Excluding certain files from moving but move hidden ones too

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, dot-files, shopt

In my deployment script I have such as code to exclude certain files.

```
shopt -s extglob
mv !(deploy.sh|file1|file2) ~/$public
```

It works almost well but ignores hidden files so they are not moved. How to improve the code to move hidden files too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `dotglob` option in bash exactly for this purpose:

```
$ touch file1 file2 .file
$ ls !(file1)
file2

$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls !(file1)
.file  file2
```